# Can i use opensocial.net library in my asp.net web application to get information on any person?

Tags: c#, asp.net, opensocial

Please suggest me any solutions or tutorials or any sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[The OpenSocial .NET Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-net-client/) doesn't seem to have much documentation online yet, so no tutorials.  [The readme](http://opensocial-net-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/readme.txt) does contain some basic getting started information.

[Pesta](http://code.google.com/p/pesta/) seems to be a more developed solution, but still not much documentation that I can see.

I've not used either so I couldn't comment on which would be better for your needs.  I guess you'll have to pick one, have a play with it, and then chat to the developers if you need more info.

The [OpenSocial website](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/) has a lot of more general information.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use opensocial javascript API in the mean time, to first fetch all the information about the person 
and then using the makeRequest Function provided by the opensocial js library to send the information to your application.

For ex:

```
function makeRequest(url,params) {


var params = {};  //This will be passed on to your page as either query string(GET) or in body(POST)
   url = "http://localhost/somepage.aspx";

   gadgets.io.makeRequest(url, response, params);
 };
```

The rest of the logic would be implemented in your aspx pages or if you want some can be done in javascript on client side.

Using this and some basic opensocial api understanding you can get your app working in to time without having to wait for the REST apis to be mature enough.

Look up the opensocial wiki for more details.